# When creating a presentation programatically, how to split a large blob of text between slides?

Tags: text, split, powerpoint, presentationml

I am creating a presentation programatically using presentationml. The full presentation will be a long table with rows having various amounts of text. What is the best way to figure out where to split the table? Or is there a way to make PowerPoint split it by itself?

Comment: Just wanted to follow up to see if the below is getting you any closer to what you need.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to split table to new PowerPoint slide when content flows off current slide using Open XML SDK 2.0](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2638046/how-to-split-table-to-new-powerpoint-slide-when-content-flows-off-current-slide)

Answer (score 1):

Check out my answer here - [How to split table to new PowerPoint slide when content flows off current slide using Open XML SDK 2.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2638046/how-to-split-table-to-new-powerpoint-slide-when-content-flows-off-current-slide-u/3176574#3176574) - this is the only way I know of *possibly* being able to do this from PresentationML.