# OpenXML, PresentationML Table Height and Row Height on word wrap

Tags: c#, powerpoint, openxml, openxml-sdk, presentationml

I'm new to Open Xml, and have created a reporting application using Open Xml SDK. It populates the data in to a table, and when the table height exceeds slide border clone the slide and  and populate the next set of data in new slides and so on. All works fine but when some of the rows have data that wraps to 2 lines fails to break in to new page at the exact place. Seems the reason is the Open Xml still returns the row height as same as the row height when there is single line of data. Is there anyway of resolving this.

Here is the a piece of code that does the pagination logic (CreateTextCell is a method that creates the text cell and return):

```
  var tbl = current.Slide.Descendants<A.Table>().First();
                var tr = new A.TableRow();
                tr.Height = 200000;
                tr.Append(CreateTextCell(product.Name));
                tr.Append(CreateTextCell(product.ProductNumber));
                tr.Append(CreateTextCell(product.Size));
                tr.Append(CreateTextCell(String.Format("{0:00}", product.ListPrice)));
                tr.Append(CreateTextCell(product.SellStartDate.ToShortDateString()));
                tbl.Append(tr);
                totalHeight += tr.Height;



                if (totalHeight > pageBorder)
                    overflow = true;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had a very similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2638046/how-to-split-table-to-new-powerpoint-slide-when-content-flows-off-current-slide) and discovered that the height of the table is not updated when populating the table via Open XML SDK. It is only updated when the presentation is actually opened in Power Point. This obviously won't help you figure out in your code when to split the table to a new slide, but if you try this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3176574/299592) it might help.

Comment: amura.. ofcourse i saw that question previously :). but we need to make sure the cell margin, padding, indentation are taken in to account when calculating the layout area for a text right ? would you mind sharing some source if you have achieved this?

Comment: You are right when you say the padding and margin need to be taken into account as well.  I never marked a correct answer on that question since I never found a solution.  I went back to our customer and got an acceptable workaround for this limitation.

Answer (score 1):

If you can you assume that all of your columns above are fixed width, except for the first column where `product.Name` is used, and your font style is the same, then you can use the following method instead of checking the table height > border.

First, open your presentation in PowerPoint and go to the slide with the table.  Enter in your fixed width column data.  Then in the first column, enter 'XXXX...." until the line breaks.  Count the number of characters before the line break.  This number will be `maxLengthBeforeBreak`

Second, clear the row from the first step above and enter in a similar row that doesn't line break.  Copy and paste this row down and fill your table in the slide until you have the maximum number of rows for the slide that looks appealing to the user.  This number of rows will be `maxTableRowsPerSlide`

Now when you fill each slide with rows, count the number of rows you insert in a `rowCount` variable.  Insert rows while `rowCount` < `maxTableRowsPerSlide`, then start a new slide.

And for each row - if the length of `product.Name` is > `maxLengthBeforeOverflow` you can increment the `rowCount` by dividing the `product.Name` length by  `maxLengthBeforeOverflow` to get the number lines this row wraps.

Comment: Thanks for the response, but the problem is that all column data are driven dynamically, and this is only a pattern of data.  there might be more other scenarios too. basically i need a common way to handle this.