# Open XML PowerPoint updated Table Height not reflected in code

Tags: c#, powerpoint, openxml, openxml-sdk

I am populating a PPT Table with dynamic content and want to get updated Table Height as content is added to it to figure out when the table overflows the slide. Due to the word wrap the table height can exceed the Slide and overflow. I have observed the Shape Offset/Extent/table Row Height etc none of the properties are updated dynamically in code.

Some Google search and Stack Overflow links ([OpenXML, PresentationML Table Height and Row Height on word wrap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9562305/openxml-presentationml-table-height-and-row-height-on-word-wrap)) suggest this is a known issue, and I haven't found any good workarounds for it. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

You have to run the PowerPoint engine, I believe. And use it to do the work.

Comment: Martin's right. Unless you are going to calculate how your dynamic changes will be reflected in the final render (which is no small task), you need to render it in PowerPoint to get the final table height.